# destroy_all (Delete selected button) unresponsive for some users

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I never had any problems with "Delete" button on any browsers, but I had 2 users complain about it - they click on the button and nothing happens. One of the users did not have any problems with the buttons in the past. The code seems OK, no errors were ever generated. All other buttons work for these users too. Any idea on why it could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also possible that these 2 users have security applications performing deep inspection on the network traffic and blocking HTTP DELETE messages.

Comment: Yeah, that was the case. I was able to fix this by adding custom header when performing an ajax request by using the beforeSend callback.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the Rails controller action can't delete it but doesn't raise an exception, rather it returns some error code that the JavaScript isn't prepared to handle so it doesn't do anything when the request is returned.